# Can't save longitude in Room database

Tags: android, kotlin, double, android-room

I've recently encountered an extremly strange proble while developing my simple location based app.

Basically, what I'm trying to achieve is getting `LatLng` object from `OnMapClickListener`, saving its `latitude` and `longitude` into Room using Dao, and then retrieving them in some other object (`fusedLocationProviderClient` `s locationCallback to be exact).

### Code

**Destination** - a simple Room Entity which has lat, lng, and timestamp as a primary key.

```
@Entity(tableName = "destinations")
data class Destination(
        @PrimaryKey var timestamp: Long = 0L,
        var lat: Double = -1.0,
        var long: Double = -1.0
)
```

**DestinationDao** - to access Room.

```
@Dao
interface DestinationDao {

    // Get the newest destination
    @Query("SELECT * FROM destinations WHERE timestamp = (SELECT MAX(timestamp) FROM destinations)")
    fun getDestination(): Destination?

    @Insert(onConflict = OnConflictStrategy.REPLACE)
    fun insertDestination(destination: Destination)
}
```

**MapsActivity** - the place where I get coordinates from user click and save them into SQLite using Room

```
map.setOnMapClickListener { latLng ->
            val destination = Destination(System.nanoTime(), lat = latLng.latitude, long = latLng.longitude)
            
            Log.d(TAG, destination.toString())
            AppDatabase.getInstance(this).destinationDao().insertDestination(destination)
            Log.d(TAG, AppDatabase.getInstance(this).destinationDao().getDestination().toString())
        }
```

**MyLocationListener** - the place where I retrieve my coordinates from Room

```
private val locationCallback = object : LocationCallback() {
        override fun onLocationResult(userLocation: LocationResult?) {
            val array = FloatArray(1)
            val destination = AppDatabase.getInstance(appContext).destinationDao().getDestination()

            Log.d(TAG, "Distance: ${array[0]} m\nlat: ${destination!!.lat}, long: ${destination.long}")
        }
    }
```

### The problem

It seems simple, but for an unknown reason, longitude never gets saved to Room! To better illustrate this, here are the logs from that `MapsActivity` snippet (-1.0 is a default value)

```
// Destination created from `LatLng` object from map click listener
D/MapsActivity: Destination(timestamp=248767407310345, lat=50.1813350498603, long=18.45104455947876)
// Destination retrieved from  Room
D/MapsActivity: Destination(timestamp=248767407310345, lat=50.1813350498603, long=-1.0)
```

I have completely no idea why is that. I tried changing Double to String and then parsing it, tried reducing the count of decimal places, I even tried changing the order of variables declaration in `Destination` class - nothing works.

If any additional data is needed, I'll post it.
Thank you in advance.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It may be so, because you called you longitude variable  - long! "Long" is reserved word in Java, not in Kotlin, I know, but, what if you try to change this row:

```
var long: Double = -1.0
```

to

```
var longitude: Double = -1.0
```

Comment: Thank you - works perfectly now! It's a pity that I can't check both 2 answers as correct :/

Comment: That's ok, don't worry ))) P.S. but  I was first ))))

Answer (score 1):

I think your problem resides in the naming of the `longitude` , you name it `long` which is a type, so maybe you can try change that name into something unique.

Comment: I can't believe I forgot that "long" is a reserved word in Java. I guess it's because I use Kotlin too much :D thank you!

Comment: I'm glade you solved your problem. Don't worry mate we all lose concentration sometimes. Happy coding :)

Answer (score 0):

"*long*" is a reserved keyword, as it's also a variable type. I had the same problem. Change it to longitude (for example) and it will work.